# emacs elisp after-change-functions does nothing

Tags: emacs, elisp

I didn't know what the reason was why after-change-functions were not working; I would evaluate:

```
(defun test-hook (change-beg change-end prev-len)
   (message "changed!"))

(add-hook 'after-change-functions 'test-hook)
```

And then a change did nothing.

I was about to ask, but then I figured it out. Still thought of leaving the answer here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that there is a variable, called `inhibit-modification-hooks`, which needs to be set to `nil`, in case it isn't:

```
(setq inhibit-modification-hooks nil)
```

Read [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Change-Hooks.html#Change-Hooks).

Comment: The big question is why this variable had a non-nil value to start with... The intention is for this to be `nil` at all times, except when the modification hooks themselves are executed or some package like `font-lock` wants to change something that should not trigger modification hooks.

Comment: I fully agree with Lindydancer. IMO `inhibit-modification-hooks` should only be `let`-bound to `t`. Note, that the lisp code from your question works for me in the scratch-buffer without fiddling around with `inhibit-modification-hooks`.

Comment: Start emacs with the `-Q` command line switch and try the code from your question again in the scratch-buffer. If it works with `-Q` this indicates a problem in your configuration.